# What makes a class a collection according to NUnit collection constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, nunit, constraints

I have a class that implements `ICollection<SomeConcreteClass>`. The NUnit collections constraints do not recognize it as a collection.

e.g. `Assert.That( sut, Has.No.Member( someObjectOfTypeSomeConcreteClass ) );` throws `System.ArgumentException : The actual value must be a collection`

and `Assert.That( sut, Is.Empty );` fails with empty `sut`.

So when is a collection a collection (according to NUnit)?

Stack Trace:

```
System.ArgumentException : The actual value must be a collection Parametername: actual
at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.CollectionConstraint.Matches(Object actual)
at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.NotConstraint.Matches(Object actual)
    MyTestFile.cs(36,0): at MyAssembly.MyTestFixture.MyTestMethod()
```

Above problems occurred with NUnit 2.4.3.0. I just tried it with 2.6. `Is.Empty` works now, but `Has.No.Member` still fails. It does not even call `Equals()` or `operator ==()`. How does it compare the collection elements? RhinoMocks `Arg<MyCollection>.List.Count( Is.Equal( 1 ) )` does now fail too.

**Conclusion:**
With NUnit 2.4 the collection constraints require implementation of non-generic ICollection for the collection to be recognized as a collection (that answers the original question). IEnumerable equality works as expected.

With NUnit 2.6 (and possibly 3.0) equality of `IEnumerable`s is checked by matching elements even if `Equals` is overridden. That's why the membership constraint does not work if the elements are `IEnumerable`s themselves. This is a known issue (https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/646786).

For details see my own answer.

Comment: can you post the full stack of the thrown exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

NUnit 2.4.3.0 tries to cast to non-generic `ICollection` which I did not implement. Works now with 2.4.

In NUnit 2.6.0.12051 there is a `NUnitEqualityComparer` which does this:

```
if (x is IEnumerable && y is IEnumerable && !(x is string && y is string))
    return EnumerablesEqual((IEnumerable)x, (IEnumerable)y, ref tolerance);
```

My collection members are IEnumerable and in case of the test are all empty. That's why the constraint believes all the instances are equal. But they are not. The NUnitEqualityComparer assumes that a class either has members (IEnumerable) or it has its own state. My collection member class (called SomeConcreteClass in the question) is both enumerable and has also other state, e.g. a Name property. Because of the way the NUnitEqualityComparer works the additional state is not compared and the empty objects with different additional state are wrongly believed to be equal.

I will discuss this with the NUnit Mailing List and will report back here.

**Edit:**

This is known behavior: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/646786

Answer (score 2):

After looking into the source code of NUnit 2.5.10: The constraint first casts the given collection to the non-generic `IEnumerable`.

EDIT: Then it runs a foreach() over the collection and compares the items. So AFAICT it should work.

What version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: ICollection<T> inherits both IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @EricSchaefer Perhaps they have additional checks or different casts in that version. Did yu try it in a more recent version?

Comment: I just tried it with 2.6. Is.Empty works now, but Has.No.Member still fails. It does not even call Equals or operator==. How does it compare?

Comment: Each item is compared using the NUnit.Framework.Constraints.NUnitEqualityComparer by default, using ObjectsEqual(object x, object y). Since it is public you could try it yourself. Basically it tests for a bunch of special cases (ex. item is a collection or a string or an array, etc). If none of those applies, it calls x.Equals(y) (i.e. the virtual method from Sytem.Object). Perhaps you didn't override Equals(object other)?

Comment: I do override Equals but SomeConcreteClass implements IEnumerable (see my own answer).

Answer (score 1):

See here http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5,

> For references, Has.Member uses object equality to find a member in a
>   collection. To check for an object equal to an item the collection,
>   use Has.Some.EqualTo(...).

So I suppose that you do not have .Equals(SomeConcreteClass) implemented, or the collection should be IEnumerable.

Comment: I want to assert that the collection does NOT contain the given object.

Comment: ... and SomeConcreteClass implements Equals

Comment: So, it's another option - IEnumerable, also @Daniel Rose states it

Comment: ICollection<T> inherits both  IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>